# Finding the kth last element of a singly linked list: answer explanation

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When you need to find the `k`th last element of a singly linlked list, the usual naive approach is to perform two passes. The first to find the length of the list and the second to iterate until the `(length-k)th` element.

Whereas the optimized version takes advantage of two pointers:

- `p1` refering to the head of the list
- `p2` being `k`th elements ahead of `p1`

This allows us to return `p1`'s element when `p2` reaches the end of the list.
I don't understand why the second approach is faster than the first when in both cases we have one pointer iterating all over the list and another until the `(length-k)th` element.

Is it due to cache optimization?

Thanks.

Comment: when length = k then 1st approach you iterate 2*k times but in 2nd approach you only iterate k times

Comment: Both algorithms have the same complexity. Which one is faster in practice depends on the actual implementation.

Comment: It would help to write the code for both approaches. Then the difference would be more apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep `p2` exactly `k` elements behind `p1`, then it doesn't really help much, since you have to do the same number of traversals all together.

You can optimize the procedure by using more pointers, though.

As you walk though the list, lets say you remember the pointer at every *(k/m)th* position, for some *m*.  You only need to remember the last *m+1* of those pointers.  Then, when you get to the end of the list, instead of iterating again from the beginning, start at the oldest pointer you remembered.  It will be between *k* and *k + (k/m)* elements behind the end, so you only have to move it forward by at most *k/m* positions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider non-uniform memory access times and a *singly linked list* of length *n*:
- in the counted iteration approach, accesses to the same node will be *n* accesses apart
- in the lagging pointer approach, accesses to the same node will be *k* accesses apart
With an LRU cache (/with each LRU cache *level*), the former is more likely to induce [capacity misses](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_performance_measurement_and_metric#Capacity_misses) than the latter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes sense.